# MaterialAutoCompleteTextView dropdownmenu/adapter not shown

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, material-design, android-adapter, google-material-icons

I have a simple setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#C9E44B"
 tools:context=".pkgTestforend.DriverAddOptionalDataFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying making a dropdownmenu visible using the simple adapter:

```
MaterialAutoCompleteTextView filled_exposed_dropdown;
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String [] randomArray = new String[3];
    randomArray[0] = " test ";
    randomArray[1] = " values";
    randomArray[2] = " ofcourse";

    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(randomArray));
    ArrayAdapter<String> h = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.list_item, items);

    filled_exposed_dropdown = view.findViewById(R.id.filled_exposed_dropdown);
    filled_exposed_dropdown.setAdapter(h);
}
```

And last but not least my list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
    />
</menu>
```

However, trying to make the dropdown visible when starting my app looks like this:

[image: example]

The issue is that right know I am only able to write a new item but the dropdown menu is not visible. What am I missing? Most of the code is based on the orginial material.io documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filled_exposed_dropdown.showDropDown()
```

is missing. ;)